# When clicking on my label, would like the url background to show instead of a bg color

Tags: javascript, image, url, selector, var

```
var links = [{label: 'Montreal', document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://unsplash.com/photos/qzgN45hseN0')|none|initial|inherit"}, 
             {label: 'Toronto', bg: '#16a085'}, 
             {label: 'Ottawa', bg: '#8e44ad'}, 
             {label: 'Gatineau', bg: '#27ae60'}, 
             {label: 'Vancouver', bg: '#f39c12'}, 
             {label: 'Winnipeg', bg: '#2980b9'},
             {label: 'Saint-John', bg: '#f39c12'},
             {label: 'Quebec', bg: '#f39c12'},
             {label: 'Edmonton', bg: '#c0392b'}, 
             {label: 'Halifax', bg: '#16a085'}, 
             {label: 'Victoria', bg: '#8e44ad'}, 
             {label: 'Hamilton', bg: '#27ae60'}, 
             {label: 'Saskatoon', bg: '#f39c12'}, 
             {label: 'Regina', bg: '#2980b9'},
             {label: 'Mississauga', bg: '#f39c12'},
             {label: 'Thunderbay', bg: '#f39c12'},];
var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
if(windowHeight === 0) windowHeight = 238;
var radius = windowHeight*0.2,
    circle = document.createElement('div'),
    borderSize = radius*0.011;
    totalArea = 98, 
    increment = totalArea/(links.length-10),
    startPoint = 0-(totalArea/2),
    fontSize = radius*0.30,
    linkSize = radius*0.25;

styleCircle();
addCircle();
addLinks();
styleLinks();

function styleCircle() {
  circle.style.width = radius*2+'px';
  circle.style.height = radius*2+'px';
  circle.style.borderRadius = radius+'px';
  circle.style.position = 'absolute';
  circle.style.top = '-'+radius*0.2+'px';
  circle.style.left = radius*-1+'px';
}

function addCircle() {
  document.body.appendChild(circle);
}

function addLinks() {
  for (var i=0, l=links.length; i<l; i++) {
    link = document.createElement('a'),
    hover = document.createElement('span');
    link.href = "#";
    link.dataset.color = links[i].bg;
    link.style.display = 'inline-block';
    link.style.textDecoration = 'none';
    link.style.color = '#fff';
    link.style.position = 'absolute';
    link.style.zIndex = 100;
    link.innerHTML = links[i].label;
    hover.style.position = 'absolute';
    hover.style.display = 'inline-block';
    hover.style.zIndex = 50;
    hover.style.opacity = 0;
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    document.body.appendChild(hover);
    link.addEventListener('mouseover', linkOver);
    link.addEventListener('mouseout', linkOut);
    links[i].elem = link;
    links[i].hover = hover;
  }
}

function styleLinks() {
  for (var i=0, l=links.length; i<l; i++) {
    var link = links[i].elem, hover = links[i].hover, deg = startPoint+(i*increment);  
    link.style.paddingLeft = radius*1.2+'px';
    link.style.fontSize = fontSize+'px';
    link.style.height = linkSize+'px';
    link.style.lineHeight = linkSize+'px';
    setTransformOrigin(link, '0px '+linkSize*0.5+'px');
    setTransition(link, 'all 0.2s ease-out');
    setTransform(link, 'rotate('+deg+'deg)');
    link.style.left = borderSize+'px';
    link.style.top = (windowHeight/2) - (windowHeight*0.1)+borderSize+'px';

    hover.style.left = borderSize+'px';
    setTransformOrigin(hover, '0px '+linkSize*0.5+'px');
    setTransition(hover, 'all 0.2s ease-out');
    setTransform(hover, 'rotate('+deg+'deg)');
    hover.style.top = (windowHeight*0.4)+borderSize +'px';
    hover.style.width = radius+(borderSize/2)+'px';
    hover.style.height = linkSize+'px';
    hover.style.borderRight = borderSize*2+'px solid #fff';
  
  }
}

window.onresize = function() {
  windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
  radius = windowHeight*0.6,
  borderSize = radius*0.021;  
  fontSize = radius*0.12,
  linkSize = radius*0.25;
  styleCircle();
  styleLinks();
}

function linkOver(e) {
  var thisLink = e.target, thisHover = thisLink.nextSibling;
  thisLink.style.paddingLeft = radius*1.25+'px';
  thisHover.style.opacity = 1;
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = thisLink.dataset.color;
}

function linkOut(e) {
  var thisLink = e.target, thisHover = thisLink.nextSibling;
  thisLink.style.paddingLeft = radius*1.2+'px';
  thisHover.style.opacity = 0;
}

function setTransform(element, string) {
  element.style.webkitTransform = string;
  element.style.MozTransform = string;
  element.style.msTransform = string;
  element.style.OTransform = string;
  element.style.transform = string;
}

function setTransformOrigin(element, string) {
  element.style.webkitTransformOrigin = string;
  element.style.MozTransformOrigin = string;
  element.style.msTransformOrigin = string;
  element.style.OTransformOrigin = string;
  element.style.transformOrigin = string;
}

function setTransition(element, string) {
  element.style.webkitTransition = string;
  element.style.MozTransition = string;
  element.style.msTransition = string;
  element.style.OTransition = string;
  element.style.transition = string;
}
```

I tried replacing the bg by url pointing toward the image instead but nothing happens, also checked if it was maybe a syntax error and tried with ('https://unsplash.com/photos/qzgN45hseN0').
Also tried [{label: 'Montreal', document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://unsplash.com/photos/qzgN45hseN0')|none|initial|inherit"},

Answer (score 0):

Right idea, but you needed to populate the right styles,and add some other css to properly display the image.

Also, you have a copy/paste issue :)

> `url('https://unsplash.com/photos/qzgN45hseN0')|none|initial|inherit"`

should not include the CSS options for `background-image`

Doing everything programmatically is fine, but you are going to need to cache any images such that the interface is less "choppy"

```js
var links = [{
    label: 'Montreal',
    bg: '#00000080',
    img: 'url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2c/Montreal_-_QC_-_Skyline.jpg")'
  },
  {
    label: 'Toronto',
    bg: '#16a08580'
  },
  {
    label: 'Ottawa',
    bg: '#8e44ad80'
  },
  {
    label: 'Gatineau',
    bg: '#27ae6080'
  },
  {
    label: 'Vancouver',
    bg: '#f39c1280'
  },
  {
    label: 'Winnipeg',
    bg: '#2980b980'
  },
  {
    label: 'Saint-John',
    bg: '#f39c1280'
  },
  {
    label: 'Quebec',
    bg: '#f39c1280'
  },
  {
    label: 'Edmonton',
    bg: '#c0392b80'
  },
  {
    label: 'Halifax',
    bg: '#16a08580'
  },
  {
    label: 'Victoria',
    bg: '#8e44ad80'
  },
  {
    label: 'Hamilton',
    bg: '#27ae6080'
  },
  {
    label: 'Saskatoon',
    bg: '#f39c1280'
  },
  {
    label: 'Regina',
    bg: '#2980b980'
  },
  {
    label: 'Mississauga',
    bg: '#f39c1280'
  },
  {
    label: 'Thunderbay',
    bg: '#f39c1280'
  }
];
var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
if (windowHeight === 0) windowHeight = 238;
var radius = windowHeight * 0.2,
  circle = document.createElement('div'),
  borderSize = radius * 0.011;
totalArea = 98,
  increment = totalArea / (links.length - 10),
  startPoint = 0 - (totalArea / 2),
  fontSize = radius * 0.30,
  linkSize = radius * 0.25;

//document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://unsplash.com/photos/qzgN45hseN0')"
styleCircle();
addCircle();
addLinks();
styleLinks();

function styleCircle() {
  circle.style.width = radius * 2 + 'px';
  circle.style.height = radius * 2 + 'px';
  circle.style.borderRadius = radius + 'px';
  circle.style.position = 'absolute';
  circle.style.top = '-' + radius * 0.2 + 'px';
  circle.style.left = radius * -1 + 'px';
}

function addCircle() {
  document.body.appendChild(circle);
}

function addLinks() {
  for (var i = 0, l = links.length; i < l; i++) {
    link = document.createElement('a'),
      hover = document.createElement('span');
    link.href = "#";
    link.dataset.color = links[i].bg;
    link.dataset.img = links[i].img;
    link.style.display = 'inline-block';
    link.style.textDecoration = 'none';
    link.style.color = '#fff';
    link.style.position = 'absolute';
    link.style.zIndex = 100;
    link.innerHTML = links[i].label;
    hover.style.position = 'absolute';
    hover.style.display = 'inline-block';
    hover.style.zIndex = 50;
    hover.style.opacity = 0;
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    document.body.appendChild(hover);
    link.addEventListener('mouseover', linkOver);
    link.addEventListener('mouseout', linkOut);
    links[i].elem = link;
    links[i].hover = hover;
  }
}

function styleLinks() {
  for (var i = 0, l = links.length; i < l; i++) {
    var link = links[i].elem,
      hover = links[i].hover,
      deg = startPoint + (i * increment);
    link.style.paddingLeft = radius * 1.2 + 'px';
    link.style.fontSize = fontSize + 'px';
    link.style.height = linkSize + 'px';
    link.style.lineHeight = linkSize + 'px';
    setTransformOrigin(link, '0px ' + linkSize * 0.5 + 'px');
    setTransition(link, 'all 0.2s ease-out');
    setTransform(link, 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)');
    link.style.left = borderSize + 'px';
    link.style.top = (windowHeight / 2) - (windowHeight * 0.1) + borderSize + 'px';

    hover.style.left = borderSize + 'px';
    setTransformOrigin(hover, '0px ' + linkSize * 0.5 + 'px');
    setTransition(hover, 'all 0.2s ease-out');
    setTransform(hover, 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)');
    hover.style.top = (windowHeight * 0.4) + borderSize + 'px';
    hover.style.width = radius + (borderSize / 2) + 'px';
    hover.style.height = linkSize + 'px';
    hover.style.borderRight = borderSize * 2 + 'px solid #fff';

  }
}

window.onresize = function() {
  windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
  radius = windowHeight * 0.6,
    borderSize = radius * 0.021;
  fontSize = radius * 0.12,
    linkSize = radius * 0.25;
  styleCircle();
  styleLinks();
}

function linkOver(e) {
  var thisLink = e.target,
    thisHover = thisLink.nextSibling;
  thisLink.style.paddingLeft = radius * 1.25 + 'px';
  thisHover.style.opacity = .5;
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = thisLink.dataset.color;
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = thisLink.dataset.img;
}

function linkOut(e) {
  var thisLink = e.target,
    thisHover = thisLink.nextSibling;
  thisLink.style.paddingLeft = radius * 1.2 + 'px';
  thisHover.style.opacity = 0;
  document.body.style.backgroundImage = null;
}

function setTransform(element, string) {
  element.style.webkitTransform = string;
  element.style.MozTransform = string;
  element.style.msTransform = string;
  element.style.OTransform = string;
  element.style.transform = string;
}

function setTransformOrigin(element, string) {
  element.style.webkitTransformOrigin = string;
  element.style.MozTransformOrigin = string;
  element.style.msTransformOrigin = string;
  element.style.OTransformOrigin = string;
  element.style.transformOrigin = string;
}

function setTransition(element, string) {
  element.style.webkitTransition = string;
  element.style.MozTransition = string;
  element.style.msTransition = string;
  element.style.OTransition = string;
  element.style.transition = string;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body></body>

</html>
```